# Memcache Admin not showing up in Modules

Tags: 6, caching

I am updating a Drupal 6 installation to support memcached. After installing the memcache plugin, and configuring it with the following in settings.php, I cannot seem to access the Memcache admin page like I can on Drupal 7.

```
$conf['cache_inc'] ='sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['memcache_servers'] = array(
  'ELASTICCACHE URL (Left out Intentionally)' => 'default'
  );
$conf['memcache_bins'] = array(
  'cache_page' => 'pages'
  );
```

I checked in modules to see if it was enabled but I do not see it there at all. All I can see is the memcache module without memcache admin.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal 6 version of memcache requires enabling the Memcache Admin module:

[image: Memcache Admin module]

Once this module is enabled, there is an option at admin/settings/memcache to display memcache statistics on a page-by-page basis:

[image: Show memcache statistics]

Comment: Hi,  so I only have the memcache option.  I do not see the memcache admin option to enable.  I am running memcache version 6.x-1.10 .  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it had something to do with the version of Memcache I was using. The Development version reintroduced Memcache Admin (from Keithm's post).